# Calling a local Windows service from Air

Tags: air

Is there a way to call out to a local Windows service (ie COM etc) from Air?

Thanks,

Philip

Answer (score 0):

AIR 2 has some new APIs that let you do it - http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/air2/ - but you won't be able to package it as an AIR file, you'll have to roll it into a native installer and deploy it that way.

=Ryan ryan@adobe.com